# Serialize Amazon SES message to string

Tags: .net, email, amazon-ses

I'm using the Amazon .Net sdk to send emails over their SES service. However, I would like to serialize the message into a string for some local logging and debugging purposes. Is there a way to do this using the sdk, or will I need to hack something else for it?

I'm not talking about just the message body, but a string containing what the whole email message would have with headers etc all included.

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: @Sergey- what's to show? I'm using the .net SES lib from the AWS sdk. I'm populating the mailmessage with content. But I don't see any way to "produce" the email content, without actually sending it.